# How to fix Anaconda Jupyter Notebook kernel error?

Tags: python

The kernel error appearing on my anaconda juppyter notebook.

I have tried to change " shell:False" to "shell:True", but it didn't work.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
>       result = await result
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
>       type=mtype))
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
>       kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
>       yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
>       self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
>       value = future.result()
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
>       yielded = next(result)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
>       super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
>       km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
>       **kw)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
>       return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 138, in launch_kernel
>       proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
>       startupinfo)
>   FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specific file.

Answer (score 5):

actually the environment that you made then you must have deleted them , there were refrences for those envs ,
soultion : used this in cmd :

```
python -m ipykernel install --user
```

see this for more help:
[here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-python-2-and-3)